# ASP.NET HiddenField value is empty after a DoPostBack event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-tabs

In a project I've inherited, I had a control called SpendSummContainer.  This control has a jquery-ui tabs object.  One of the requirements is that the selected tab remain selected after on of the columns has been placed in edit mode (the column has an 'edit' link that performs a DoPostBack and places the column in edit mode).

All of the below is from the SpendSummContainer control.

The tabs are the standard jquery-ui tabs, like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">Stuff goes here</div>
<div id="tabs-3">Stuff goes here</div>
<div id="tabs-2">Stuff goes here</div>
</div>
```

Then, I have a ASP.NET hidden field on the form,

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="activeTab" runat="server" />
```

Lastly, I have the following javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#<%= activeTab.ClientID %>').val(ui.index.toString());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've verified that the hidden field is correctly getting populated by alerting back the value after the value is set.

The problem is that when the DoPostBack is performed, the activeTab.value property is empty.

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim selectedTab As string = activeTab.Value
End Sub
```

So my question is, how so I maintain the value of the hidden field after the DoPostBack?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a small but complete example to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you replace `select` with `activate` event, and use `ui.newTab.index()`?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">1 Stuff goes here</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">2 Stuff goes here</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">3 Stuff goes here</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                $('#<%= activeTab.ClientID %>').val(ui.newTab.index());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="activeTab" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `DoPostBack`? Do you mean that the edit link is an ASP.NET button control that is posting back to the form or do you mean that it's a jquery ajax function? If it's the latter, then it's not actually a postback but rather a new request from the point of view of the server.

That's the only thing I can think of for the value not persisting, because if it is a form submission then by the Page_Load event, the webforms lifecycle should have repopulated the hidden value with the value passed in the form.